# Kotlin Not Configured : Android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

[image: Error which i am getting]

I am able to run the project successfully. but unable to resolve this issue which is showing "kotlin Not Configured". I tried every solution for that but its always showing in the currently active file.

Please help.

Comment: Tried `Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin in Project`?

Comment: tried but its says "there aren't configurator available" ..do you know why?

Comment: Is your gradle plugin on? And is synced all the libraries?

Comment: post both gradle files here also

Answer (score 6):

Delete the .gradle and .idea file and restart the project. This seem to work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Click on Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin in Project
then choose the configurator, any one from:

1. Java with Gradle
2. Android with Gradle

Comment: "There aren't configurators available"

Answer (score 4):

Simply hitting "*Sync Project with Gradle Files*" did the job for me.
[image: Screenshot of the button in Android Studio]

Answer (score 2):

try to upgrade the kotlin version in build.gradle file
`ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'`
also in the build.gradle app module file make sure `implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"`
in the dependencies section ,
if you see at any time update the gradle option , do so

Answer (score 2):

Furthermore, if you find a line
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
in your build.gradle, you may see the warning message:
Avoid using + in version numbers, can lead to unpredictable and anrepeatable builds.
Click on "Replace with specific version", then the current installed version replaces the "+". (For example, "1.3.2")
In my case the "kotlin not configured" message and a lot of "errors" in the kotlin file disappeared.

Comment: I did this and the kotlin not configured still keeps appearing. I don't think this is the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it can fix by keep the version of `kotlin-gradle-plugin` up to date. Check the version here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions

**File for configuration Location**

```
Project -> build.gradle
```

//example: update this dependence:

```
dependencies {
  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"
}
```

Comment: I get "Unresolved reference: classpath"

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue after updating to latest android electric eel. So those of you who had a kotlin project which working fine and after update failed to sync gradle files or build projects with error

**"Kotlin not configured"**.

I think this answer might help. I'm not sure if this is the right way to do but this was a life saver for me since I was working with an old project with older dependencies and kotlin version

**Just click on the gradle offline toggle and try syncing the project and building it in offline mode. That's it !!!**

[image]

No need to change any version or other changes. I hope this helps and save your time.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me randomly in one of my projects, and i just did Build Gradle and worked again

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35484924)